# Bind data to ShieldUI grid based on pagesize and pagecount?

Tags: gridview, shieldui

I have the requirement that while binding data to ShieldUI grid I want to load data based on pageSize and pageNumber.For e.g if pagesize is 10 and when user on 2nd page of grid then it will fetch the records from  11-20.I have written the stored procedure like only I am not able to pass startindex and pagecount to my controller action.Currently what happend that it initalliy fetch all the records from database because of that performance is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at the following example:

http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-databinding/remote-data

You should use the remote-> read option of the DataSource. In the url you should put your controllerName/action url. Then in the data method you make the mapping between your action parameters and the grid parameters. In the odataParams dictionary you set the url params. $skip is the number of records to be omitted and $take is the number of records to be fetched by your controller action from database.

Comment: I used remote in the following way.
 remote: {
                    operations: ["skip", "take"],
                    read: {
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "http://localhost:52816/Grid/getGirdData",
                        dataType: "json",
                        skip: 5,
                        take: 10
                    },
                },
Also how can I set parameter to odataParams dictionary object.It's better if you provide be an example that explain the same.

Comment: I have mapped between action parameters and the grid parameters successfully.Now issue is that in database I have 30000 records and when grid is loaded because of skip and take parameter it fetch only between this records in that case my page size remains 1.It show paging depending on number of records in databse.So pleae let me know how can I set paging.

Comment: You should set a total (schema.total) so that the Grid to knows how many are the total number of records. Example here: http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-databinding/remote-data